# SIGMA LENS & Nikon D3300

Tags: autofocus

I have just purchased a Sigma APO DG 70-300mmF/4-5.6 Lens Nikon F mount. It will not work on Auto Focus no matter what setting I use,even though it is sold as being A/F O.K. with Nikon F mounts on D3300 cameras. Any help out there, please.

Comment: No matter if there is a way out or not. I'll suggest not to use an F mount lens on D mount camera or vice versa or whatever it is. Your camera is much costlier & delicate stuff. If it gets damaged then it'll be a bad thing. Even Nikon officially don't discourage to use the lens of other companies but strictly discourage to use other mounts. Anyways Sigma or Tamron will not give you the sharp image at 300mm as that will a Nikkor lens will provide but not that bad. :)

Comment: @NewBee the D3300 is an F-mount camera, as are all Nikon DLSRs. The F-mount versions of 3rd party lenses are specifically for Nikon bodies.

Comment: @NewBee _Sigma or Tamron will not give you the sharp image at 300mm as that will a  Nikkor lens will provide_. This is overly broad, and only true in specific lens comparisons. I guarantee a Sigma 120-300mm is sharper at 300mm than a Nikon 28-300mm.

Answer (score 3):

The D3300 requires lenses with focus motors in the lens, so several lenses will not auto focus on the D3300.  Nikon AF-S lenses can focus, and the Sigma APO DG has such a motor, and it should auto-focus.

However, there are two routine ways that you can disable auto focus, when desired.

Many lenses have a switch on them to set Manual focus mode (lens has switch positions M or A, for Manual or Auto focus). Not certain about this lens, but probably has it.  If present, make sure it is not on Manual focus.  The B&H description of it says "full time Manual focus override", so it must have it.
Check your instruction manual that comes with the lens.

Also the cameras also have a switch or menu to set Manual focus.  Then no lens will auto focus (check to see if that is true now. If not true, then this is not the issue). 
For the D3300, setting this mode is described on page 74 of the Larger D3300 Reference Manual, available Free at  http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/21/D3300.html

This free Reference manual is like the User Manual, but 370 pages instead of 124 pages, much larger and more complete, more topics.

Either way will diable AutoFocus.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I am researching lenses in more depth. No pun intended.